# How to detect if a byte is a line break when reading from a CSV file byte by byte - C#

Tags: c#, arrays, csv, byte, filestream

I need to read from a CSV file byte by byte (Note: I don't want to read line by line).
How can I detect if the byte that was read is a line break ?
How to know that end of line was reached ?

```
int count = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER];

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{              
    // Read bytes form file until the next line break -or- eof 
    // so we don't break a csv row in the middle

    // What should be instead of the 'xxx' ?

    while (((readByte = fs.ReadByte()) != 'xxx') && (readByte != -1))
    {
        buffer[count] = Convert.ToByte(readByte);
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: probably != '\n' ?

Comment: Yes, thanks, '\n' worked great too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

New line character has decimal value `10` or hex value `0xA`. In order to check new line character compare the result against `0xA`

```
int count = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER];

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{              
    // Read bytes form file until the next line break -or- eof 
    // so we don't break a csv row in the middle

    // What should be instead of the 'xxx' ?

    while (((readByte = fs.ReadByte()) != 0xA) && (readByte != -1))
    {
        buffer[count] = Convert.ToByte(readByte);
        count++;
    }
}
```

When `readByte` is equal to `10` or `0xA` in hex, the condition will be false.
Have a look at the [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for more information.

#### UPDATE

You might also want to define a constant like `const int NEW_LINE = 0xA` and use that instead of just `0xA` in the while statement. This is just to help you figure out later what that `0xA` actually means.

Comment: Some files use `\r\n` (`0x0D 0x0A`) as newline, so you might want to check for the `0x0D` too.

Comment: Yes, this is true. However, what is very interesting, Microsoft documentation states that `\r\n` are used on non-Unix systems, while `\n` is used on Unix-based systems. If you try using `\n` on Windows, it will create a new line and carriage return.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But files could come from everywhere (for example a Unix logfile read on a Windows system). Since this is C#, the file might contain `0x0D 0x0A`, depending on where it was created. So I guess it's best to be prepared for both cases when reading a file.